# Set custom image for android task manager

Tags: android, privacy, taskmanager, android-security

My app is displaying private data so, I need to hide it when user clicks task manager. I know I can use FLAG_SECURE to prevent app screenshot, but is there a way to set static image to be displayed instead? How do I do that?

Comment: did you find an answer to this ?

Comment: Hi, nope, I used FLAG_SECURE to hide app content while it is in the background(task manager). No custom curtain was added, since my primary goal was privacy of data and curtain image was just a 'nice to have' I did not spent time investigating any further.